# Extending body to cover z-indexed footer when there isn't enough content

Tags: html, css

I'm having difficulty in getting the main portion of the body to extend over the top of the footer.  I have tried several methods such as setting 100% heights to the divs like this:

```
#mainbody{
    transition: all 50ms;
    padding: 0 10%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I have included the url where you can find an example of the site I'm working on, basically I want the white area of the page to extend over the grey footer to the bottom of the page.
http://stackoverflow.adamrapley.com/

Comment: Just a subdomain, I only created it to dump the files somewhere haha :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set **all** parent divs height to 100%.

Add this css:

```
html,body,#mainbodyholder,#mainbody{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I've done that, but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: @AutomatedRandomated true, except on `#mainbodyholder`. Although, when I inspect code, I see you did set the height on `html` and `body` but for some reason, they are not aplying and I can't see any overrides... comfiusing. Try doing it with some code inspector like firebug or other and you will se what I am talking about.

Comment: Ah, that css has made it extend now, but it's made it extend by a significant amount and now when you scroll up, the margin at the bottom is larger for some reason so the body scrolls up too far

Comment: well I see you are using normalise.css and simplegrid.css maybe there is some wierd overrides...

Comment: Ah, simplegrid isn't being used but I'll have a look at normalise to see if there's anything going on there. Surely the styles.css should override normalise.css though because it's referenced after it in the html?

Comment: well you are now having the "common responsive problem" is that on 100% height, your margins, paddings and border expand the element even more than 100% you may have a look at th `border-box` CSS3 property to fix that